# Google Sheets - TEXTJOIN with multiple Criteria

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

I'm looking to give out a **textjoin** of **multiple, horizontal cells**, depending on **three criteria**:

I want the function to **find the email** from column E in the sheet called "UGC_Product_Pick" --> If it **also shows A1**(test_project) in **column X**, as well as **A2** (test_client) in **column Y** --> **TEXTJOIN** the info from **columns B, C And D** within this row.
I hope this makes sense.

I tried a couple different approaches. **The one that has worked best up to this point is:** IF AND with TEXTJOIN.
But for some reason the IF function won't find the email, even though it's right there. Also the TEXTJOIN will only give out the info from all rows, not only the one matching all the criteria.

Can anyone help?

```
=IF(AND(UGC_Product_Pick!Y:Y=A1;UGC_Product_Pick!X:X=A2;UGC_Product_Pick!W:W=E4);TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;UGC_Product_Pick!B:B;UGC_Product_Pick!C:C;UGC_Product_Pick!D:D);"-")
```

Comment: adding sample input and output data would allow users to understand the problem and provide suggestions

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Here's a copy of the sheet. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xNymFPJ_9aAcKe6IOabqOtoOwNFQhAgqsxb78cEfVq0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried this formula now: 
=IF(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(UGC_Product_Pick!X:X=A1;UGC_Product_Pick!Y:Y=A2;UGC_Product_Pick!W:W=E4)));TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;UGC_Product_Pick!B:B;UGC_Product_Pick!C:C;UGC_Product_Pick!D:D);"-")

It seems do be doing what it's supposed to. The only issue is, it's joining all text from the selected columns. I only want the info from the row meeting all the criteria. Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(UGC_Product_Pick!B:D; 
 UGC_Product_Pick!Y:Y=A1;
 UGC_Product_Pick!X:X=A2;
 UGC_Product_Pick!W:W=E4));;9^9)))
```

### update:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(
 IF(UGC_Product_Pick!B:D="";;UGC_Product_Pick!B:D&","); 
 UGC_Product_Pick!Y:Y=A2;
 UGC_Product_Pick!X:X=A1;
 UGC_Product_Pick!W:W=E4));;9^9))); ",$";))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped a bit. I added the query part in with my initial IF Function. Now only the correct cells need to be joined. See comment above

Comment: @alto97 answer updated